# OpenGL freetype Text, y offset to the topmost border of character

Tags: c++, opengl, text, render, text-rendering

in OpenGL for drawing text i'm using freetype. i have succedded render the text for now, but i still got the problem where the characters does not point to the rightly y coordinate (those characters are not flat).

look at the picture below, i've made 'Loading...' text.

[image]

as you can see the the placement of y coordinates were incorrectly. it make me confused.
this the code what i've done:

```
class FontBitmap{
    private: 
    struct character_info {
      float bw; // bitmap.width;
      float bh; // bitmap.rows;
    } c[256];  
    int next_p2 (int a )
    {
        int rval=1;
        while(rval<a) rval<<=1;
        return rval;
    }
      GLuint  texture[256]; //character textures
    public:
      FT_Library  library;   /* handle to library     */
      FT_Face     face;      /* handle to face object */
      FontBitmap(){}

      void Print(char * str,GLfloat x,GLfloat y){ //the function where to render the text
          glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
          glEnable(GL_BLEND);
          glPushMatrix();
          glTranslatef(x,y,0.0f);
          for(int i = 0;i < strlen(str);i++)
          {       
              glPushMatrix(); 
              glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D,texture[str[i]]);
              glTranslatef(x,0,0);  //the placement of per character
              glBegin(GL_QUADS);
              glTexCoord2f(0,0); glVertex3f(0,0,0.0f);
              glTexCoord2f(1,0);glVertex3f(c[str[i]].bw,0,0.0f);
              glTexCoord2f(1,1); glVertex3f(c[str[i]].bw, c[str[i]].bh ,0.0f);
              glTexCoord2f(0,1); glVertex3f(0, c[str[i]].bh,0.0f);            
              glEnd();
              x +=c[str[i]].bw;
              glPopMatrix();
          }
          glPopMatrix();
          glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
          glDisable(GL_BLEND);
      }

        FontBitmap(char * filePath, int size) //the constructor
        {
            glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);    

          if (FT_Init_FreeType (&library)) 
          {
              //on error
              return;
          }
         if (FT_New_Face(library,filePath,0,&face))
         {
             //on error
             return;
         } 
         FT_Set_Pixel_Sizes (face, 0, size);
         for (unsigned long i = 33; i < 256; i++) 
         {
           if(FT_Load_Char(face, i, FT_LOAD_RENDER))
           {
               //on error;
               return;
           }
           int width = next_p2( face->glyph->bitmap.width );
           int height = next_p2( face->glyph->bitmap.rows );

           c[i].bw = width;
           c[i].bh = height;

            GLubyte* expanded_data = new GLubyte[ 2 * width * height];

            for(int j=0; j <height;j++) {
                    for(int i=0; i < width; i++){
                            expanded_data[2*(i+j*width)]= expanded_data[2*(i+j*width)+1] = 
                                    (i>=face->glyph->bitmap.width || j>=face->glyph->bitmap.rows) ?
                                    0 : face->glyph->bitmap.buffer[i + face->glyph->bitmap.width*j];
                    }
            }
            glGenTextures(1,&texture[i]);
            glBindTexture( GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture[i]);
            glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D,GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER,GL_LINEAR);
            glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D,GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER,GL_LINEAR);
        glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT,1);
            glTexImage2D( GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, width, height,
                      0, GL_LUMINANCE_ALPHA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, expanded_data );
            delete [] expanded_data;
         }

        }

    };
```

Comment: you might want to check out freetype [glyph metric](http://www.freetype.org/freetype2/docs/glyphs/glyphs-3.html) on how to correctly render a character.

Comment: i've looked around to the link, and got the handler that set the distance from origin to the character. it is bearingY. but when i try, it was always give large value?

Comment: you might want to divide by 64, reason is on the same page.

Answer (score 0):

Ascent and Descent are the two FreeType metrics of interest to you in regards to your question.

Horizontal spacing between characters are controlled with Advance and [Kerning](http://www.freetype.org/freetype2/docs/glyphs/glyphs-4.html)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.  After many days of researching and scratching my head, I finally found the solution.  Note freetype's wording to describe yMin :

> "If yMin is negative, this value gives the glyph's descender."

Therefore, in actuality, xMin, yMin are expected to be treated as **sizes** in your calculations, not **positions**.

If you know how OpenGL works, position ranges from -1.0f to +1.0f, while, size ranges from 0.0f to 1.0f;

Therefore, considering this, if you are performing a calculation in openGL between a size and a position, the rule is :

1. If you are multiplying or dividing (basically scaling), do as normal.  Such as `scaled_position = position * size`
2. If you are adding or substracting, you have to first convert size to position (or vise versa).  To convert size to position, you multiply by 2. This is because `distance(position) = (+1.0f) - (-1.0f) = 2.0f`, while, `distance(size) = (1.0f) - (0.0f) = 1.0f`. Such as `offset_position = position + (size * 2)`

---

Ofcourse, you can change the sign of 'size' in the 'offset_position' calculation base on the direction of the offset.  Therefore, to accurately render a font on a line, you will do something similar to the following snippet:

```
//from freetype (pixels)
float xmin = bbox.xMin / 64; //FT_Glyph_Get_CBox
float ymin = bbox.yMin / 64;
float x = (pen + xkern + advance) + (xmin * 2); //pen - user position, xkern - freetype, advance - keep track of to space out chars
float y = (base + ykern) + (ymin * 2); //base - user position
//normalize for opengl (+1.0f : -1.0f), also, you could have normalize of the data before you did the calculations, if you wanted
x = x / VIEWPORT_WIDTH; //user defined
y = y / VIEWPORT_HEIGHT; 
//Now the x and y positions are guaranteed to draw the info on the baseline accurately and accurately space out the characters
//TODO: DRAW YOUR TEXT HERE ...
advance += face->glyph->advance.x / 64.0f / VIEWPORT_WIDTH; //update your advance
```